# How to assign some part of dynamic array to whole static array

Tags: c, arrays

The size of dynamic array is the twice the size of static array. I want to assign the values which starts from (N/2)-1 to N-1 of dynamic array to whole static array.

The only way is copying the values with a loop?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N=100, pSize=4, lSize, i;
    double *A;

    lSize=N/sqrt(pSize);
    /* memory allocation */
    A=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);

    double B[lSize];
    /* memory allocation has been done */

    /* initilize arrays */
    for(i=0; i<lSize; i++){
        B[i]=rand()% 10;
    }

    A=B;
    for (i=0; i<lSize; i++){
        fprintf(stdout,"%f\n", A[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) function to copy the data. For your example you want to copy the last half of A to B so could do something like:

```
memcpy(&B[0], &A[lSize-1], lSize * sizeof(double));
```

Note: On the MinGW compiler I was using, it was requiring that I declare the destination as &B[0], I thought I could get away with just B. It may be due to configuration I have (I don't use the C compiler all that much, normally just use g++ for quick C++ test cases).

Comment: You'd better copy more than `lSize` bytes if you want the whole array to be full.  A `double` is usually bigger than 1 byte.

Comment: Good catch, this site needs peer code review before answers are committed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) to copy contiguous chunks of memory around.

Answer (score 0):

Your program leaks your allocation, which is probably bad - is that `A=B` intended to be where you would put the code that copies the array?

It may be possible, depending on your architecture, to do a copy without a CPU loop (via a call to a DMA engine or something).  In standard C, you have no choice but to loop.  You can either do it yourself or you can call [`memcpy(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memcpy/), [`memmove(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memmove/), or [`bcopy(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/bcopy/) if you prefer to use the library's implementations.

Comment: Yes it is intended for copying process and this is a sample code to see the results. my acctual code is for parallel programming project which is a matrix-vector multiplication in cartesian topology. i'm sending the multiplication results with vector derived type.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you need to use memcpy:

```
#define  N  100
int staticarray[N];
int *pointer = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int)*N*2 );
memcpy( staticarray, (pointer + ((N/2) - 1)), sizeof(int)*N );
```